# Visual Studio 2012 File Input

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, file-io

I am looking for a way to have a file entered by the user to be used in a program that I have created in C++. When in project mode, this works fine, but when just using the executable program, my program seems to be unable to locate a file entered by the user (even through paths). Is there something in properties that I need to adjust? Also, I've read how to link files to the program, but since the user will be entering there own file name, I would like this to not be restricted to files that are known.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute the program outside your IDE, put that file beside the .exe file. If you want your program works simultaneously in two modes, you can use *absolute path*.

IDE's way is to change *working directory* where it's in PROJECT > Properties > Debugging > Working Directory. Change it to where your .exe file is. A directory with name Debug or Release.

[image]